# Increase packetSize on Tomcat AJP Connector

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, apache, mod-jk

For some reason, default packetSize (8KB) on AJP connector in server.xml does not suffice my need. My header size gets exceeded 8KB. So I need to set it to 16KB.
As I am runnning apache in front of tomcat, so I need to set max_packet_size directive to 16KB also in workers.properties.

Can you please explain if there is any issue/ impact in increasing packetSize ?
I am using tomcat 7.0.25

Thank you very much.